# What does 'per unit charge' mean?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, potential-energy, terminology

When we say "potential is the potential energy per unit charge", what does a 'unit charge' actually mean?

In a worked example from my textbook, when they find the potential difference, they divided the work done by $+1.602 \times 10^{-19} C$. But this entire worked example was talking about a proton in an electric field. What if this worked example was dealing with an electron in an electric field?. Then would we divide by $+1.602 \times 10^{-19} C$ or $-1.602 \times 10^{-19} C$?

Comment: It's not clear to me what they are doing. Please provide the full context of the worked example.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes in physics, to generalize the understanding of certain quantities like energy, we use the "per unit whatever"; this whatever being mass, charge, or any other characteristic of the system we are studying.

In an electrostatical background, as I assume is your example, we might want to "forget" what kind of particle we are talking about. Since the electrostatical potential energy depends on both the charge distribution (which creates the field to study) and a target charge (the proton in your case), it is a more general description when we eliminate the proton characteristics, dividing by its own charge. In this way, we are able to describe the energy of other particles which might be in the range of the field creating the distribution.

In conclusion, we could say that we use this kind of terms to reduce the description of a system. If the potential energy per unit charge (which is usually called electric potential) is $u$  and the potential energy is $U$, it is straightforward that
$$U=qu$$
with $q$ being any charge you could be studying (proton, electron...). I hope this also helps you answer yourself the last question you posed.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity pulls in mass.

- An object with a certain mass feels a certain pull.
- An object with double the mass feels double the pull.
- An object with three times the mass feels three times the pull.
- Etc.

With a specific object we can tell the specific pull, the exact gravitational force.

Gravity is a force field that at each point in space pulls in everything differently according to their mass. How can we describe how much gravity pulls *in general* at a particular point? Sure, we could use an example by choosing an object and telling how hard gravity would pull in this object. But it might be another object in question at another time, so isn't there a general way to describe gravity at this point?

The easiest method might be to simply tell the force *per kilogram*. With this info (along with assumption of the force being linear with mass) it is easy to scale up the force to what it would be for a particular choice of object. Suddenly you could simply multiply the force field value (the force-per-mass) with the relevant mass - so this force-per-mass measure it kinda useful.

This is therefor the general way that we describe force fields. If the force field strength is proportional (linear) to the relevant property, then force-per-unit is often a perfect way to describe such a field.

An electric field in your case is of this reason described to you as force-per-Coloumb. If you are asked to find the field strength at a particular point, then you can simply add some random test charge to this point, measure the electric force on it and then divide with its charge. Then you'd know the field strength at that point as force-per-unit-charge for future use with other charges.